# LeetCode 149: Max Points on a Line

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you would like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

Given `n` points on a 2D plane, find the maximum number of points that lie on the same straight line.

#### Example 1:

- Input: `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`
- Output: 3

```
^
|
|        o
|     o
|  o  
+------------->
0  1  2  3  4
```

#### Example 2:

- Input: `[[1,1],[3,2],[5,3],[4,1],[2,3],[1,4]]`
- Output: 4

```
^
|
|  o
|     o        o
|        o
|  o        o
+------------------->
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

#### Inputs

```
[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
[[0,0],[94911151,94911150],[94911152,94911151]]
[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[131,131],[3111,3111],[31,31],[13,13],[113,11],[5,5]]
```

#### Outputs

```
3
2
8
```

#### Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

struct Solution {
    static const inline int maxPoints(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &points) {
        int max_points = 0;

        for (int index_i = 0; index_i < points.size(); index_i++) {
            int overlap = 0;
            int y_on = 0;
            int curr = 0;
            map<pair<int, int>, int> points_map;

            for (int index_j = index_i + 1; index_j < points.size(); index_j++) {
                if (points[index_i] == points[index_j]) {
                    overlap++;

                } else if (points[index_i][0] == points[index_j][0]) {
                    y_on++;

                } else {
                    const int x = points[index_i][0] - points[index_j][0];
                    const int y = points[index_i][1] - points[index_j][1];
                    const int gcd = greatest_common_divisor(x, y);
                    points_map[ {x / gcd, y / gcd}]++;
                    curr = std::max(curr, points_map[ {x / gcd, y / gcd}]);

                }

                curr = std::max(curr, y_on);
            }

            max_points = std::max(max_points, curr + overlap + 1);
        }

        return max_points;
    }

private:
    // std::gcd
    static inline const int greatest_common_divisor(const int a, const int b) {
        if (not b) {
            return a;

        } else {
            return greatest_common_divisor(b, a % b);
        }
    }
};
```

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-points-on-a-line/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-points-on-a-line/discuss/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-points-on-a-line/solution/)

Comment: `const inline int` Way to unreadable. Simply use: `int`. It has exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code Review

- Prefer `int` to `const inline int`. See Previous review.
- Prefer to pass by const reference
- Prefer to put the `&` next to the type (not the parameter).
  Its part of the type information (note this is the opposite of C).

  ```
    static const inline int maxPoints(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &points)
  ```

---

This is absolutely fine (I have not problems with it).

```
        int max_points = 0;
```

But most (I have no real metrics for this, but in my experience) tend to use "CamelCase" rather than "Snake_Case" naming convention.

---

Prefer to use pre-increment rather than post increment

```
        for (int index_i = 0; index_i < points.size(); index_i++) {
```

The reason is that C++ code can simply be changed by changing the type used. Now pre/post fix increment on an integer has exactly the same type. But if we change the type used for the iterator then pre/post increment can be slightly different in cost. The standard implementation of iterators (the most common thing used in loops) will give you a slightly more expensive operation (in theory) than a pre-increment. Thus the standard advice is to always use the pre-increment to make sure you always use the most efficient operation.

---

Be aware of the new range based operator.
Not sure it totally helps here. But keep in mind the range based operator:

```
        for (int index_i = 0; index_i < points.size(); index_i++) {
            auto& item = points[index_i];

            // STUFF
        }

        // can be simplified to:
        for (auto& item: points) {

            // STUFF
        }
```

---

Your assuming that `using namespace std;` is somewhere above you.

```
            map<pair<int, int>, int> points_map;
```

Don't. Even using `using namespace std;` is considered bad pactice.

---

Not very common to see the use of `not`. It is much more common to use `!`.

```
        if (not b) {

        ----

        if (!b) {
```

For most C developers this will be the normal.